# How does ThrowawayController in Spring MVC get the parameters from a request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is an example of using ThrowawayController in Spring MVC:

```
public class DisplayCourseController 
    implements ThrowawayController {
  private Integer id;
  public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }   
  public ModelAndView execute() throws Exception {
    Course course = courseService.getCourse(id);                       
    return new ModelAndView("courseDetail", "course", course);   
  }
  private CourseService courseService;
  public void setCourseService(CourseService courseService) {
    this.courseService = courseService;
  }
}
```

With its declaration in the xml file:

```
<bean id="displayCourseController"
    class="com.spring.mvc.DisplayCourseController"
    singleton="false">
  <property name="courseService">
    <ref bean="courseService"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Both of these two pieces of code do not specify how the parameter **id** in a request is found identified. Can anybody tell me how it works?

EDITED:
I think the logic would probably be using **getParameterNames()** and **getParameter()** to retrieve all the parameters, and using java reflection to get the corresponding setter.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Spring 2.5, then you should not use ThrowawayController, it'll be removed in Spring 3.

Comment: You both mention it. I will keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to search for this class, so if you're still using it, be aware that it's not even present in Spring 3.

From `ThrowawayControllerHandlerAdapter` Javadoc

> This implementation binds request
>   parameters to the ThrowawayController
>   instance and then calls execute on it.

So, I'd say that the handler adapter uses standard property editors to convert named request parameters into the type specified in the `setX` methods.

You might be able to confirm this by passing, in your example code above, an invalid number as id in the request, eg: foo?id=not-a-number and see where the exception gets thrown.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that we have the same speculation. I will give the experiment a try, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the interface "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.throwaway.ThrowawayController" is removed since Spring3.1.x

Why don't you use annotations ?